# DataGrid View is not updating with new information from an Access Database table

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to build a C# app that works with MS Access to store lottery numbers for statistical processing. I have been able to verify that the Access DB Table has been updated with the new entries, but I cannot seem to get the DataGrid view to show/refresh the data.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnAddRecord_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime drawDate;
    int ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4, ball5, ball6;

    drawDate = dtpDrawingData.Value;
    ball1 = int.Parse(txtBall1.Text);
    ball2 = int.Parse(txtBall2.Text);
    ball3 = int.Parse(txtBall3.Text);
    ball4 = int.Parse(txtBall4.Text);
    ball5 = int.Parse(txtBall5.Text);
    ball6 = int.Parse(txtBall6.Text);

    try
    {
        conn.Open ();
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand ();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO TriplePlay (DrawDate, Ball1, Ball2, Ball3, 
        Ball4, Ball5, Ball6) VALUES (#{drawDate}#, {ball1}, {ball2},{ball3}, {ball4}, 
        {ball5}, {ball6})";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Added", "Update Made", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        dgvJackpotTriplePlay.Update();
        dgvJackpotTriplePlay.Refresh ();
        triplePlayBindingSource.MoveLast();
        conn.Close ();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The only data that I am currently able to display is what I had originally input into Access prior to starting this project and linking to the database.

Can someone please provide so information on how to refresh the DataGrid View with the new information as it is getting to the DB.

TIA

Comment: Look for `DataGridView` + `DataTable` + `OleDbDataAdapter` + `OleDbCommandBuilder` [ + `BindingSource`]. You'll find ~10,000+ questions about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh the `DataGridView` (`dgvJackpotTriplePlay` in your case) with the new data after an insert operation, you must re-fetch the data from the database and bind it to the `DataGridView`.

Here's how you can achieve this:

**Create a method to populate the DataGridView:**
This method will retrieve the data from the database and set it as the data source of the `DataGridView`.

```
private void PopulateDataGridView()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TriplePlay", conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    dgvJackpotTriplePlay.DataSource = dt;
}
```

**Call this method at the end of your insert operation:**
After successfully adding the new record to the database, call the `PopulateDataGridView` method to refresh the `DataGridView` with the updated data.

```
private void btnAddRecord_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... (your existing code)

    try
    {
        conn.Open ();
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand ();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO TriplePlay (DrawDate, Ball1, Ball2, Ball3, 
        Ball4, Ball5, Ball6) VALUES (#{drawDate}#, {ball1}, {ball2},{ball3}, {ball4}, 
        {ball5}, {ball6})";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
        conn.Close ();

        // Refresh the DataGridView with the updated data
        PopulateDataGridView();

        MessageBox.Show("Record Added", "Update Made", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

**Initialize the `DataGridView` when the form loads:**
When the form first loads, you should also call the `PopulateDataGridView` method to initially populate the `DataGridView` with the data from the database.

```
private void YourFormName_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateDataGridView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things the wrong way around. You are adding new data to the database and then expecting the grid to magically get that data from there. That's not going to happen because the grid has no connection to the database. It is connected to a `DataTable`, which is a local data structure. In order for the new data to show in the grid, you'd have to query the database again and retrieve that new data into the `DataTable`. What's the point of that when you already had that data though?

What you should be doing is adding the new record to the `DataTable` first. It will then display in the bound grid immediately. You then use a data adapter or table adapter to save the changes from that `DataTable` back to the database.

That adapter might be a new object or it might be the same one you used to populate the `DataTable` in the first place. You would have called `Fill` to query the database and retrieve the data. You call `Update` to save changes. Obviously you need to have configured it appropriately. You need to populate the `SelectCommand` in order to retrieve data using `Fill`. Likewise, you need to populate the `InsertCommand` and/or `UpdateCommand` and/or `DeleteCommand` in order to insert, update and delete records in the database using `Update`.